# Git: Get changes from master to a remote branch

Tags: git, rebase, git-remote

I am working on a project and we have development branches. Lets say we have branches: `master, A, B`

Let's say that history looks like this right now:

```
   7  
   |   
   6  merge commit
   |/ |
   4  |
   |  |
   3  |
   |  |
   a  5   b
    \ | /
      2 
      |
      1
      |
      m
```

where m, a and b are the branches and numbers are just commits. So I did some work on master, then created branch a, then did some work on a AND some work on master and then some work on a and then merged.

**Question is: ** What is the right way to get the commit `5` into branch a?

If it was a local branch I could just

```
git checkout a
git rebase master
```

But a is a remote branch and I know it is not safe to mess with remote history like that. What is the correct way of getting changes from master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create a local branch a tracking remote/a
2. git checkout a
3. git merge master
4. git push

You already merged one way; was there a specific reason you reached straight for rebase instead of merge in the other direction?

Is it because you previously used some other VCS with broken merges? If so I can reassure you that git is perfectly capable of finding the common ancestor and performing a sane merge here.

Comment: Well...to be honest I haven't thought of merging the other way!! My mind froze on rebase

Comment: Fair enough! As a rule of thumb, it's safest to stick with merge for publicly-visible changes, and keep rebase for cleaning up local commits before pushing.

Answer (score 2):

Just merge master into a:

```
git checkout a
git merge master
```

Done a thousand times, no problem.

Comment: If I merge like this I would get the `merge branch a` commit from master to my branch. Is that acceptable?

Comment: You will get it, yes. And I think it should be acceptable, but depends on what you think is acceptable in a git log.